# segmentation fault, cast to/from pointer to/from integer of different size

Tags: c, pointers

The code below is an example from a book i'm reading, i tried making sure it's completely accurate to the code in the book, but it still doesn't work.
When running it i get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
Apparently it's an example that "With the data types defined by typecasting, anything that is big enough to hold a four-byte value can work the same as a void pointer". I would like to know why it's not working and maybe learn how to do it in a way that runs properly.
Sorry ahead of time if it's the cause of a dumb mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int i;

        char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
        int int_array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

        unsigned int hacky_nonpointer;

        hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;

        for(i=0;i<5;i++) { // Iterate through the int array with the int_pointer.
                printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n", hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));
                hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);
        }

        hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) int_array;

        for(i=0;i<5;i++) { // Iterate through the int array with the int_pointer.
                printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n", hacky_nonpointer, *((int *) hacky_nonpointer));
                hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);
        }
}
```

Comment: when was this book written? Modern systems are x64, which means pointers are 8 bytes, not 4 (`int`s are most likely still 4 bytes). You [can see](https://godbolt.org/z/vqdjeb1fM) this `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size` among the others. Trying to cram 8 bytes into 4 will lead to truncation, which will be an entirely different memory address (one you don't own, hence the seg fault) when you try to dereference.

Comment: @yano
It was published in 2003, with a second edition in 2008. *This is the second edition.

Comment: yeah, that's ancient. Pointers were 4 bytes back then on x86. Recommend a newer book,, or understand that moving forward and maybe skip this part. Or, instead of `unsigned int` you can try `unsigned long`, that's probably 8 bytes. Use `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(<type>));` to figure sizes of everything on your system.

Comment: As the remaining warnings say, `"%p"` for `printf` still expects a `void*` argument, but [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7G7E69TW9) is more what you expect.

Comment: @yano
Thanks a lot, i've been stuck in this part for some time. I'm new to Stack Overflow, could you care to explain to me what to do with the post now that you gave me an answer i'm satisfied with?

Comment: heh well. . it's frowned upon to answer in the comments, but some times that just kind of happens. I'll type up an answer unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: ah, closed on the dupe. In the middle of an answer, that was a waste of time. But you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MKj8Ebe9b) what's happening.